# Headset volume control messed up

Tags: audio, headphones

My headset has Volume Up / Volume Down buttons used to work fine. However, recently, they affect the external speaker volume instead of the headset volume, meaning they don't help at all when I am on a call.

It's USB. I have tried reinstalling the driver, and restarting the computer.

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: It's a USB set.

Comment: This normally happens after a change has occurred. Did you recently update the PC, install any software?

Comment: Just a printer, and some small pieces of software like Dia (to draw diagrams)

Comment: Did you try a system restore? What sound card are you using? Is the graphics, audio and chipset driver up to date?

Comment: Would rather not a system restore, as it can cause worse problems. I don't know what sound card I am using. I updated the drivers a few months ago - now the driver update program is not working. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: try and find what sound card you have, it may tell you in service manager or in control panel > sounds

Comment: @DaveRook Device Manager shows under Sound, video and game controllers: IDT High Definition Audio CODEC, Intel(R) Display Audio, Microsoft LifeChat LX-3000

Comment: Control Panel > Sound. Under recording, is the correct device selected. Also, under Playback, is the correct device selected

Comment: @DaveRook They are the default devices for communication, and they work (eg for Skype). However the inbuilt volume control works wrong. Note I can change the volume manually using the appropriate slider in the volume control window.

Comment: `However the inbuilt volume control works wrong` - what inbuilt volume?

Comment: @DaveRook On the USB wire between the headset and the USB port there are 3 buttons - Mute, Volume Up, Volume Down. They all work except that the volumes manage the wrong volume and don't affect the headset volume.

Comment: My  suggestion is still system restore. it was working, now isn't, this suggests a change is made, since you don't know what the change is a restore is a good option.

Comment: @DaveRook Just realised that I had turned System Protection off, since this is recommended for a SSD, http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-performance-tweak,2911-3.html, so system restore is not an option.

Comment: either reinstall the software or roll back the driver within device manager

Comment: @DaveRook Did that - uninstalled from device manager, restarted, installed automatically, and also tried installing the driver from microsoft's web site. Thanks.